# gitlab-ci jest in monorepo with interdependencies

Tags: jestjs, gitlab-ci, monorepo

Im using jest to run tests in my monorepo.
These tests have interdependencies to other subpackages of the monorepo.

Everything works great localy.
But the gitlab-ci pipeline fails, cause it cant resolve the interdependencies...

Simplyfied project structure:

```
packages
-core
--src
---core.js
--package.json
-advanced
--src
---advanced.js
---advanced.test.js
--package.json
.gitlab-ci.yml
jest.config.js
package.json
```

Simplyfied jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  projects: ['packages/*'],
  rootDir: __dirname,
  roots: ['<rootDir>/packages'],
  testMatch: ['**/*.test.js'],
}
```

Simplyfied core/package.json:

```
{
  "name": "@myProject/core",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Simplyfied advanced/package.json:

```
{
  "name": "@myProject/advanced",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@myProject/core": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Simplyfied advanced.test.js:

```
import thisthat from 'randomBibX'
import others from 'randomBibY'
import core from '@myproject/core'

//doTests
```

Simplyfied package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  }
  "devDependencies": {
    "randomBibX": "^1.0.0",
    "randomBibY": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Simplyfied .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: node:10
stages:
  - setup
  - test
setup:
  stage: setup
  script:
    - yarn config set cache-folder /cache/.yarn
    - yarn install --non-interactive --frozen-lockfile
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1hour
    paths:
      - node_modules
      - "packages/*/node_modules"
jest:
  stage: test
  dependencies:
    - setup
  script:
    - "[ ! -d node_modules/ ] && yarn install --non-interactive --frozen-lockfile"
    - yarn test
```

The error:

```
FAIL packages/advanced/src/advanced.test.js
   ● Test suite failed to run
     Cannot find module '@myProject/core' from 'advanced.test.js'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was, to build the project before testing

Improved .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: node:10
stages:
  - setup
  - test
installAndBuild:
  stage: setup
  script:
    - yarn config set cache-folder /cache/.yarn
    - yarn install --non-interactive --frozen-lockfile
    - yarn lerna run build --stream
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1hour
    paths:
      - node_modules
      - "packages/*/node_modules"
jest:
  stage: test
  dependencies:
    - installAndBuild
  script:
    - "[ ! -d node_modules/ ] && yarn install --non-interactive --frozen-lockfile"
    - yarn test
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I think it's related to cache because if I call the test script inside the "setup" stage it works